# What's the meaning of (beat sense into) & (beat something blues)?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

What is meant by these two expressions:

1- **beat** (some) **sense into**?

2- **beat** something **blues**?

*For example:*

Beat The Virus Blues / Beat The Budget Blues. (Those two are taken from magazines' covers.)

Comment: Beat sense into = beat in the hope that a lesson is learned by the victim.  ....................................Beat  the blues = overcome sadness

Comment: _The blues_ here refers to unhappiness caused by a particular circumstance. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blues . Presumably the articles provide suggestions for overcoming problems caused by the coronavirus pandemic, and by a government budget which leaves people financially worse off. _Beat some sense into_ refers to the dubious practice of beating someone to make them change their mind to what the person doing the beating considers a sensible attitude.